# Why does the same code work in a servlet but not in a Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gdata, picasa

This code works in a servlet:

```
PicasawebService service = new PicasawebService("Picasa test");
PicasawebClient picasaClient = new PicasawebClient(service);
List<AlbumEntry> albums = picasaClient.getAlbums("cgcmh1@gmail.com");
for(AlbumEntry album: albums){
    resp.getWriter().println(album.getTitle().getPlainText());
    List<PhotoEntry> photos = picasaClient.getPhotos(album);
    req.setAttribute("photos", photos);
}
```

So I tried putting it in a Spring controller by using `model.addAttribute` (below) instead of `req.setAttribute` (above):

```
PicasawebService service = new PicasawebService("Picasa test");
PicasawebClient picasaClient = new PicasawebClient(service);
List<AlbumEntry> albums = picasaClient.getAlbums("cgcmh1@gmail.com");
for (AlbumEntry album : albums){
    logger.warn("albums:" + album.getTitle().getPlainText());
    List<PhotoEntry> photos = picasaClient.getPhotos(album);
    model.addAttribute("photos", photos);
}
```

However, the Spring code fails to find any albums in Picasa while the servlet code finds them successfully.

Anyone know why this is the case?

In both cases they are using [this version of the PicasawebClient](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/photos/PicasawebClient.java) and [this version of the PicasawebService](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/client/photos/PicasawebService.java).

Comment: What does your JSP look like?  What does your Spring config look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
model.addAttribute("photos", photos);
```

will override the `photos` attribute of the map on each iteration, so you will only be able to access the last album.